# How to remove all tags with text in it PHP

Tags: php, regex

How to remove all tags with text in it PHP

I read other SO answers but it didn't work as expected. I have tried `/<[^>]*>/` and other reg expression but wasn't able to make it work. And `strip_tags` only deletes tags without text in it.

Here is the example I have : http://www.regexr.com/3dmif

How to delete tags that are in tag? Like:

```
<a>test</a> hello mate <p> test2 <a> test3 </a></p>
```

The output should be : **hello mate**

Comment: So, it's not only the tags you want gone, but also the text within the tags?

Comment: Can't make use of str_replace() ?

Comment: Maybe https://regex101.com/r/kV8lP2/1? That won't work for layered elements or self closing elements though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting your result using regular expression will be really hard because it would need to understand the html scope, which regex can't so using it would be a really **bad solution**.

A simple solution to your problem would be simply to parse the html and get **only** the text nodes on the **first dimension**.

This code snippet solves your given problem but you will have to extend / change it depending on your needs.

```
<?php 
// creates a new dom document with your html
// contents
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML("<a>test</a> hello mate <p> test2 <a> test3 </a></p>");

// always use the body element
$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

// prepare your  text
$text = '';

// itarete over all items on the first dimension
// and check if they are a text node:
foreach($body->childNodes as $node)
{
    if ($node->nodeName === '#text')
    {
        $text .= $node->nodeValue;
    }
}

var_dump($text); // hello mate
```

Cheers.

**Edit:**

As @splash58 pointed out, your can also use xpath to access the text nodes directly.

```
<?php 
// creates a new dom document with your html
// contents
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML("<a>test</a> hello mate <p> test2 <a> test3 </a></p>");
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$text = '';

foreach ($xpath->query("/html/body/text()") as $node) 
{
    $text .= $node->nodeValue;
}

var_dump($text); // hello mate
```

Comment: Add root level `<html>$string</html>` and use xpath `/html/text()`

Comment: @splash58 True that would be even shorter.

Comment: Yes, this is definately better than using regular expressions. In the end that will always fail. In your first code example it would be better to replace `'#text'` by `XML_TEXT_NODE`.

Comment: @Mario Thank you very much for your help. It does work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet solves your given problem. it will helpful to you.

```
<?php

$title = "<a>test</a> hello mate <p> test2 <a> test3 </a></p>";

$result = preg_replace("(<([a-z]+)>.*?</\\1>)is","",$title);
echo $result;   // hello mate

?>
```

Comment: This wil fail on multiline and if you add more layers: `<a>test</a> hello mate <p><p> test2 <a> test3 </a></p> test4</p>`

Comment: @vishal Thank you very much for your help.